# What is the difference between "apply" and "mapcar" in Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

```
(defun describe-paths (location edges) 
(apply #'append (mapcar #'describe-path (cdr (assoc location edges)))))
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What are the similarities? Or, is there another question lurking here?

(Links from elisp, because that is what I know. The quotes are just excerpts and the links contain examples which may or may not be relevant in a particular "Lisp".)

[mapcar](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/emacs-lisp-intro/html_node/mapcar.html)

> > mapcar is **a function that calls its first argument with each element of its second argument, in turn**. The second argument must be a sequence.

[apply (in Calling Functions)](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Calling-Functions.html)

> > apply calls function with arguments, just **like funcall but with one difference: the last of arguments is a list of objects, which are passed to function as separate arguments**, rather than a single list. We say that apply spreads this list so that each individual element becomes an argument.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 4):

**The `describe-paths` function (from the text based adventure game in [Land of Lisp](http://landoflisp.com/)!) generates descriptions for the paths going from a given location. Page 74-77 in *Land of Lisp* explains the roles of `mapcar` and `append` in the example.**

The `(cdr (assoc location edges))` provides a list of all paths going from the location, such as these for the `living-room` location:

```
((GARDEN WEST DOOR)
 (ATTIC UPSTAIRS LADDER))
```

The `mapcar` calls the function `describe-path` for each of the paths, collecting the path descriptions into a list where each of the sublists is a path description:

```
((THERE IS A DOOR GOING WEST FROM HERE.)
 (THERE IS A LADDER GOING UPSTAIRS FROM HERE.))
```

Next the `append` function is applied to the list of path descriptions, concatenating it into a flat list:

```
(THERE IS A DOOR GOING WEST FROM HERE. THERE IS A 
  LADDER GOING UPSTAIRS FROM HERE.)
```